# How to get the next and previous element in an array, Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have this array and need to replace its elements by the multiplication of its previous and next.

I do the following:

```
   array.each_with_index{|element, index|
      next_element = array[index+1]
      previous_element = array[index-1]
    }

   array.map! {|a|
      if a == array.first
        a = a * next_element
      elsif a == array.last
        a = a * previous_element
      else
        a = next_element * previous_element
      end
      }
```

I expect the following result:

```
array = [4, 1, 6, 7, 9, 3, 0]       #given array
array = [4, 24, 7, 54, 21, 0, 0]    #array replaced
```

I get the following error:

`` undefined local variable or method `next_element' for Arrays:Class ``

Is there a easy way of getting the previous and next element of a given array element?

Am I using the `array.map!` method right?

Comment: Provide expected behaviour for first and last elements of array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work:

```
array = [4, 1, 6, 7, 9, 3, 0]

[nil, *array, nil].each_cons(3).map { |l, m, r| (l || m) * (r || m) }
#=> [4, 24, 7, 54, 21, 0, 0]
```

The array is surrounded by `nil` values, so each element has neighbors. `each_cons(3)` then yiels each element along with its neighbors to `map` which multiplies the left (`l`) with the right (`r`) neighbor, falling back to the middle element (`m`) if one of the neighbors happens to be `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following,

```
[array[0..1].inject(:*)] + array[0..-2].map.with_index { |x,i| x * (array[i+2] || array[i+1]) }
# => [4, 24, 7, 54, 21, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `next_element` and `previous_element` inside the loop, so they become undefined at the end. This is a simple work around of your code, I'll assume that 
you want to keep first and last element unchanged. You dont need to use `map`

```
array.each_with_index do |element, index|   
  if element != array.first && element != array.last
    array[index] = array[index+1] * array[index-1]      
  end 
end 

array => [4, 24, 168, 1512, 4536, 0, 0]
```

This is not what you expected, why? Because your element, `array[index]` will change after each iteration you can print array after each iteration to see the result

I would suggest you to use another array to save the value of array, like this

```
b =[]
array.each_with_index do |element, index|
  b[index] = array[index]
    if element != array.first && element != array.last
  b[index] = array[index+1] * array[index-1]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [`each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) would be a good fit here:

```
[array.first] + array.each_cons(3).map { |p, _, n| p * n } + [array.last]
#=> [4, 24, 7, 54, 21, 0, 0]
```

This needs some more work (e.g. if the array is empty this will return `[nil, nil]`) but I'm sure you can figure out these edge cases.

Comment: One issue with `each_cons/1` is that you're going to get a fence post situation. Consider using `array.each_cons(2).map do |a, b| ... end` where the array is [1,2,3,4].  You will get the following pairs to each call:  `[1,2], [2,3], [3, 4]`.  This means that inside your body, you will have to operate on [x,_] ,but on the rest [_, x]. Ideally, the call should return either `[nil,1], [1, 2], [3, 4]`, or `[1,2], [2,3], [3, 4],[4, nil]`.